# Flip clock not working after deploying on netlify

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am facing some issue with a jQuery plugin which I have used in my project to show countdown. Locally it is working fine but when I deploy it on Netlify others things works except the countdown. I am giving the code for your better understanding.
(Note: It is a basic index file & I have used the plugin by downloading.)

**Index.html**

```
<!-- Countdown attachments-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Assets/flipclock.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Assets/flipclock.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ------ -->




<div class="clock"></div>



<script>
        var clock;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            // Grab the current date
            var currentDate = new Date();

            // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
            var futureDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0); /* yyyy,mm,dd formate*/

            // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
            var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

            // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
            clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
                clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                countdown: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

**It looks like this:**
click [here](https://ibb.co/NnLs6wC)

**But it should look like this:**
click [here](https://ibb.co/jz8PP6B)

Comment: What errors do you see on your devtools console? Is the flip clock code loading OK? Ie have you uploaded it to the right folder?

Comment: A Haworth      There are several errors showing.          1) Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cryptomania21.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.        2)Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined  3) Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when looking at your code. Yes, as it says you need to load jquery using https, currently it’s trying  to use http.

Comment: I don't know how to load jquery using https, would you kindly explain more.!

Comment: You have http in the jsquery script loading src, try https